# Best alternative to SSH in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to connect to a remote host machine on both Linux and Windows without SSH, using an Ansible playbook. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection.html#adding-connection-plugins) it is possible to extend Ansible with a connection plugin such as SNMP or message bus. You can get a list of possible connection plugins with the command below.

```
ansible-doc -t connection -l
```

For Windows, usually WinRM is used. SSH does also work on Windows and takes less effort to set up securely in my opinion.

When using WinRM you have a few options, the one that you should use depends on the type of environment. Depending on what option you use, it can take some effort to set up properly.

1. [Basic Authentication](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#basic) (generally insecure, not recommended);
2. [Certificate Authentication](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#certificate) (similar to SSH keys);
3. [NTLM](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#ntlm) (older protocol that supports domain users);
4. [Kerberos](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#kerberos) (generally recommended when running in a domain environment).
5. [CredSSP](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#kerberos) (supports stuff like credential delegation)

Generally I would recommend SSH for Linux, it's easy to set up and secure. Your question does not specify why you can not use SSH, so I can't advise on that.

Comment: Actually its restricted from client to use SSH, but we have all work done before using ssh connection so we actually finding alternate of SSH for remote connection in ansible

Comment: It might be worth checking out [ansible-pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html) which inverts the architecture and makes hosts pull playbooks from a repository that can then be executed locally. I've never used it, but you might be able to set it up without needing SSH.

Comment: Do you have any example that how to use ansible-pull as an alternate of SSH

Comment: Well I think that the main part of ansible-pull is that it takes a playbook from a GitHub repository for example, you should be able to do that through HTTPS. This eliminates having to connect to the host via SSH. The only thing that you should have to do is set up a cron-job that pulls the configuration every X amount of time.

I don't have any actual examples that I could show you and the functionality seems to be poorly documented.  I can't find anything except for [the  ansible-pull command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html). That's what you run using cron.